# 'People are to find these ideas throughout his later work'

Tags: passive-voice, modal-verbs, be, modality

According to Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, page 206,

> With a passive the interpretation can be strong deontic, “must” ([ii]
>   *He is to be left alone*), or weak dynamic, “can” ([iii] *These ideas are to be found throughout his later work*); **there is no active
>   counterpart to the latter**.

I do not understand what it means by "active counterpart".

Comment: Presumably, it refers back to the *passive*.

Comment: He is to be left alone **P** <===> **A** [We/People/Do-gooders ...] are to leave him alone. /// These ideas can be found throughout his later work **P <===> A**  [We/People/Students ...] can find these ideas throughout his later work. /// These ideas are to be found throughout his later work **P** <=/=> **A** *[We/People/Students ...] are to find ..XXX.

Comment: You received an answer here:[link](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/active-counterpart-to-passive-quasi-modal-be-with-weak-dynamic.3625418/)

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/613772/2085).